# Closest point to road intersections with GeoPandas and Shapely

Tags: intersection, shapely, linestring, geopandas

I have a **geopandas** dataframe, where each record's geometry field is made up of a **LineString**.  Each **LineString** represents the points which make up a road.  I'd like to find the locations of all road intersections from this data.  Currently, I have nested for-loops which take each record and pairwise compute the *intersection* of the two **LineString** objects.  My questions are:

1. Is this the best way to go about doing this?  Even 10 pair-wise computations is yielding ~78000 intersection points.  Perhaps I need to store in a spatial database like rtree if there are indeed that many intersections, but this seems inefficient...
2. My ultimate goal is, I have spatial points, for which I'd like to find the closest intersection point.  If there is a better or more efficient method than first finding all intersections and then finding the closest point, I'd love to hear suggestions.

Comment: You can likely change your approach to calculate the Cartesian product of your dataframe. From there you can generate a new column that is the intersection of your two spatial columns. That would then allow a quick nearest neighbor query. Doing this in PostGIS with a proper spatial index would also work very well.